# php nested IF statements to hide content (possible syntax error)

Tags: php

I cannot see what is incorrect here, I'm trying to hide an entire element if all (and some) options are empty, but it is hiding everything even though at least options are filled in.

My code:

```
    <?php $sitename = get_bloginfo( 'description' );
          $phone1 = get_option( 'show_phone1' );
          $phone2 = get_option( 'show_phone2' );
          $email = get_option( 'show_email' );
          $address1 = get_option( 'show_address1' );
          $address2 = get_option( 'show_address2' );
          $town = get_option( 'show_town' );
          $county = get_option( 'show_county' );
          $postcode = get_option( 'show_postcode' );
    if ( ! empty( $sitename ) && ( ! empty( $phone1 ) || ! empty( $phone2 ) ) && ! empty( $email ) && ( ! empty( $address1 ) && ! empty( $address2 ) ) && ! empty( $town ) && ! empty( $county ) && ! empty( $postcode ) ) : ?>
        <div class="site-contact">

        <?php if ( ! empty( $sitename ) ) : ?>
            <span><?php echo get_bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></span>

        <?php endif; if ( ! empty( $phone1 ) ) : ?>
            <span><?php echo get_option( 'show_phone1' ); ?></span>

        <?php endif; if ( ! empty( $phone2 ) ) : ?>
            <span><?php echo get_option( 'show_phone2' ); ?></span>

        <?php endif; if ( ! empty( $email ) ) : ?>
            <span><a href="mailto:<?php echo get_option( 'show_email' ); ?>" title="Send and email to <?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>"><?php echo get_option( 'show_email' ); ?></a></span>

        <?php endif; if ( ! empty( $address1 ) ) : ?>
            <span><?php echo get_option( 'show_address1' ); ?></span>

        <?php endif; if ( ! empty( $address2 ) ) : ?>
            <span><?php echo get_option( 'show_address2' ); ?></span>

        <?php endif; if ( ! empty( $town ) ) : ?>
            <span><?php echo get_option( 'show_town' ); ?></span>

        <?php endif; if ( ! empty( $county ) ) : ?>
            <span><?php echo get_option( 'show_county' ); ?></span>

        <?php endif; if ( ! empty( $postcode ) ) : ?>
            <span><?php echo get_option( 'show_postcode' ); ?></span>

        <?php endif; ?>

        </div><!-- .site-contact -->
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Any help is much appreciated, please bare in mind I (obviously) do not code PHP.. I'm just trying my hand at some editing.. which is always fun.

Comment: This isn't actually a WP question, but I'll answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that address2 is not required, is that right? If so, then you have an 'and' operator where you should have an 'or' operator:

```
( ! empty( $address1 ) && ! empty( $address2 ) )
```

should be

```
( ! empty( $address1 ) || ! empty( $address2 ) )
```